# Fetch and pull git repo on boot

Tags: cron, git

I have a cron job set up to run `boot.sh` on reboot, and log the input to debug.txt.

```
@reboot cd /home/<user>/code/seasons-pixel-clock/ && (sudo bash boot.sh) > debug.txt
```

The contents of `boot.sh` are as follows:

```
cd /home/<user>/code/seasons-pixel-clock
sudo git fetch
sudo git pull
sudo python3 src/main.py
```

Now from the above, I would expect git pull and git fetch to occur on boot. However, neither occurs. `Main.py` does execute, however. Moreover, no error is printed in debug.txt.

What is the correct way to git pull/fetch on boot?

Comment: Can you please share contents of `debug.txt`? Why do you use `sudo` with git?

Comment: Didn't you forgot to put shebang in your shell script e.g. `#! /bin/sh`? I'm not sure if it is absolutely necessary in this case, but might be a good idea to add it.

Comment: @Vadim the contents of the file are empty, as I said.... I added the shebang, but that didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: how do you know that `main.py` is executed? Also, how about `sudo`, is there a reason for you to use it with git? Can you add `echo test` or better `echo $PWD`  line in the script to check if it will appear in the `debug.txt` file?

Comment: I know main.py works because it interfaces with a LED display, and the LED display turns on.

Yes, I should have mentioned that I have debug text printing... debug.txt just doesn't catch it for some reason. Running main.py in the console normally does display the text however. 

sudo is required for main.py. Since I also have a git user attached to root, I just used it there too.  The same result occurs either way.